# How to connect this 3 wire AC motor?

Tags: capacitor, motor, ac, wiring, single-phase

I have this NEW [heat recovery unit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HRU100-Recovery-Extract-Supply-Condensation/dp/B00DICFOOO) from Amazon (shady quality, branded as made in UK but actually made in China) with this motor inside. It was supposed to have two speeds (Low/Hi).

**Question:**
How to connect the wires?
Assuming that BROWN and BLUE and the "main" 230V wires, where do I connect the BLACK and WHITE?

---

Here is what I got by disassembling the unit. (Yes, the schematic I show is correct. I double checked.) Did they connected the capacitor to the wrong wire?
[image: three wire motor diagram HRU100]

---

Here is the user manual, which **makes no sense**:

[image: HRU100 user manual PDF]

---

Internal resistance measurement:

- Blue-Black = 500ohm
- Red-Black  = 680ohm
- Blue-Red   = 1200ohm

Comment: Is it a 3 phase motor? Did it work before?

Comment: @SolarMike - the unit is NEW. The user manual says it is designed for "normal" (single phase) power grid (220V/230V).

Comment: Does it fail? Did you ever wire it with light and switch to Hi?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - that is my point! which color is "High" (at the motor)??? Are the black and white wires high and low? In this case, if the black wire is the Hi, then the motor spins terribly slow!

Comment: White is high with the 1uF cap and 0.1uF is slow which agrees with your schema and their block diagram  except for hi lo reversed

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - small correction - the capacitor is 0.4uF not 0.1uF :)

Comment: That makes more sense for < half speed.  still too slow?  This is a 2 phase motor using 1 phase power and Cap phase shift for the other phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hand-drawn diagram in your question shows blue and red reversed. It is possible that is an acceptable means of reversing the rotation of the motor. However it is also possible that the motor was manufactured with wire colors that do not match the manual. The resistance readings tend to indicate that interchanging the blue and red to reverse in **not** acceptable, but it might work even if it is not recommended by the manufacturer.

If the heat recovery unit is a manufactured item that you believe to have been installed and working properly previously, you should probably assume that the internal capacitor connection is correct. Connect the HI LO switch to white and black, respectively. Connect neutral to brown. Connect the switch and blue to power to run.

Testing:

If at all possible, measure the current when you first turn it on and compare with the rated current. Also check direction of rotation. That will prove if blue and red are properly selected assuming the product is viable at all. Resistance values indicate black/brown/5 must be hot or neutral and red, blue, 2, 3, 4 must be connected to the opposite side of the line.

Comment: many many thanks. considering the atrocities present in the "user manual" I would not doubt that the capacitor is connected to the wrong wire!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (PS: as you can see the manual was translated with Google Translate probably from Chinese).

Comment: the unit is NEW. I just didn't had the courage to installing for the last 2 years, considering the mistakes in the manual.

Comment: PS: why "brown to ground"? from what I know, brown is always the "live" wire. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-live-earth-and-neutral-wire

Comment: "assuming the product is viable at all" - good point :)    But people that commented on Amazon.co.uk say that the device is working! Probably they connected some wires randomly, without even opening the manual and it worked. The ignorance is bliss!

Comment: I said brown to neutral, not ground. That is only because it is closet to the manual. Hot and neutral can usually be swapped in a motor with no problem. It is more common to put switches on the hot side. It is not uncommon to put thermal cutoff in the neutral. I would use the "switch the hot side" rule as the overriding one lacking some very important reason not to do so.

Comment: Ignorance is bliss and Amazon products of unknown parentage make life exciting.

Comment: sorry, sorry. I wanted to say "neutral" instead of "ground". sorry!

Comment: PS: I don't see any kind of device/box/component that could be a "thermal cutoff" switch. Unless they put it DIRECTLY into the motor!!!!!!!! I will not open the motor.

Comment: Before posting here, I connected ONLY brown and blue to the mains and the motor spins into the correct direction. but it is slow. I made some smoke and it barely sucks it from 3-4cm distance.

Comment: Connecting only brown and blue connects only the presumed main winding to power. Without the aux winding, the motor can not develop much torque and could start in either direction. Your results are what I would expect and probably don't prove much. The thermal cutoff should be inside the motor. It may be covered by motor windings.

Comment: Note that Sunnyskyguy EE75 has discovered that the hand sketch has HI and LO reversed in terms of position. The higher value capacitor will provide the higher speed. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So what i would try is (colors based on block colors NOT WIRE)

- Hi->black
- lo->White
- Neutral->Brown
- EARTH ->yellow/Green
- For the last wire you need to split the hot before the switch so an always hot wire is going to blue (always meaning when you want it to run)

Comment: And assuming that brown and blue and the "main" 230V wires, where do I connect the Hi and Low? To the ground????

Answer (score 0):

Your blue is a common, red is control, and the black and brown are your supply connections. I'd say if it's a two speed motor the brown is for normal and the black is for high speed